# getting trouble with execlp()

Tags: c, ncurses

I am using execlp to implement a net based command but its not working.I am using

```
execlp("telnet 0 5000","telnet 0 5000",(char *)NULL);
delwin(menubar);
delwin(messagebar);
endwin();
```

but its not working else than that if i replace telnet 0 5000 with ls it will work but the output comes on the same screen means on the GUI and noecho get activates automatically and output of ls comes in a pretty unusual manner.

below is my full code .

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define ENTER 10
#define ESCAPE 27
void init_curses()
{
        initscr();
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_
BLUE);
        init_pair(2,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE);
        init_pair(3,COLOR_RED,COLOR_WHITE);
        curs_set(0);
        //noecho();
        keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
}
void draw_menubar(WINDOW *menubar)
{
        wbkgd(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(2));
        waddstr(menubar,"PARALLEL");
        wattron(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        waddstr(menubar,"CON.");
        wattroff(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        wmove(menubar,0,20);
        waddstr(menubar,"SERIAL");
        wattron(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
        waddstr(menubar,"CON.");
        wattroff(menubar,COLOR_PAIR(3));
}
WINDOW **draw_menu(int start_col)
{

        WINDOW **items;
        items=(WINDOW **)malloc(9*sizeof(WINDOW *));

        items[0]=newwin(10,19,1,start_col);
        wbkgd(items[0],COLOR_PAIR(2));
        box(items[0],ACS_VLINE,ACS_HLINE);
        items[1]=subwin(items[0],1,17,2,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[1],"Shailendra singh",1);
        items[2]=subwin(items[0],1,17,3,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[2],"THIVNENT TECH",2);
        items[3]=subwin(items[0],1,17,4,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[3],"THINCLIENT",3);
        items[4]=subwin(items[0],1,17,5,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[4],"SOLARCOMPUTING",4);
        items[5]=subwin(items[0],1,17,6,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[5],"TECHNOCRATS",5);
        items[6]=subwin(items[0],1,17,7,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[6],"SENSORS",6);
        items[7]=subwin(items[0],1,17,8,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[7],"NCURSESLIB",7);
        items[8]=subwin(items[0],1,17,9,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[8],"GCC COMPILER",8);





        wbkgd(items[1],COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wrefresh(items[0]);
        return items;
}

void write_data0()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
 if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1;  }
 if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.0 \n", fp);
fputs("Server type = R ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}
void write_data1()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
 if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1; }
  if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1;}
fputs("172.16.254.1 \n", fp); 
fputs("Server type = T ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}

void write_data2()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");  
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1;}
if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }

fputs("172.16.254.2 \n", fp); 
fputs("Server type = C ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}

void write_data3()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
 if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1; }
  if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.3 \n", fp);
fputs("Server type = R ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}

void write_data4()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1;}
 if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.4 \n", fp); 
fputs("Server type = T ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}
void write_data5()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1; }
 if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.5 \n", fp);
fputs("Server type = C ", ft); 
fclose(ft); 
fclose(fp); 
}
void write_data6()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                 return 1;}
 if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.6 \n", fp); 
fputs("Server type = R ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp); 
}
void write_data7()
{FILE *fp,*ft;
 fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
 ft = fopen("servertype.txt","w");
if(fp == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"file.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
 if(ft == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"servertype.txt\" for appending\n");
                return 1; }
fputs("172.16.254.7 \n", fp); 
fputs("Server type = T ",ft); 
fclose(ft);
fclose(fp);
}


WINDOW **draw_menu1(int start_col)
{

        WINDOW **items;
        items=(WINDOW **)malloc(9*sizeof(WINDOW *));

        items[9]=newwin(10,19,1,start_col);
        wbkgd(items[9],COLOR_PAIR(2));
        box(items[9],ACS_VLINE,ACS_HLINE);
        items[1]=subwin(items[9],1,17,2,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[1],"SHAILENDRA SINGH",1);
        items[2]=subwin(items[9],1,17,3,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[2],"thivnent tech",2);
        items[3]=subwin(items[9],1,17,4,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[3],"THINCLIENT",3);
        items[4]=subwin(items[9],1,17,5,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[4],"SOLARCOMPUTING",4);
        items[5]=subwin(items[9],1,17,6,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[5],"TECHNOCRATS",5);
        items[6]=subwin(items[9],1,17,7,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[6],"SENSORS",6);
        items[7]=subwin(items[9],1,17,8,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[7],"NCURSESLIB",7);
        items[8]=subwin(items[9],1,17,9,start_col+1);
wprintw(items[8],"GCC COMPILER",8);





        wbkgd(items[1],COLOR_PAIR(1));
        wrefresh(items[9]);
        return items;
}
void delete_menu(WINDOW **items,int count)
{
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<count;i++)
                delwin(items[i]);
        free(items);
}
int scroll_menu(WINDOW **items,int count,int menu_start_col)
{
        int key;
        int selected=0;
        while (1) {
                key=getch();
                if (key==KEY_DOWN || key==KEY_UP) {
                        wbkgd(items[selected+1],COLOR_PAIR(2));
                        wnoutrefresh(items[selected+1]);
                        if (key==KEY_DOWN) {
                                selected=(selected+1) % count;
                        } else {
                                selected=(selected+count-1) % count;
                        }
                        wbkgd(items[selected+1],COLOR_PAIR(1));
                        wnoutrefresh(items[selected+1]);
                        doupdate();
                } else if (key==KEY_LEFT || key==KEY_RIGHT) {
                        delete_menu(items,count+1);
                        touchwin(stdscr);
                        refresh();
                        items=draw_menu(20-menu_start_col);
                        return scroll_menu(items,8,20-menu_start_col);
                } else if (key==ESCAPE) {
                        return -1;
                } else if (key==ENTER) {
                        return selected;
                }
        }
}
int main()
{
    int key;
    WINDOW *menubar,*messagebar;

    init_curses();

    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    menubar=subwin(stdscr,1,80,0,0);
    messagebar=subwin(stdscr,1,79,23,1);
    draw_menubar(menubar);
    move(2,1);
    printw("Press F1 or F2 to open the menus. ");
    printw("ESC quits.");
    refresh();

    do {
        int selected_item;
        WINDOW **menu_items;
        key=getch();
        werase(messagebar);
        wrefresh(messagebar);
        if (key==KEY_F(1)) {
            menu_items=draw_menu(0);
            selected_item=scroll_menu(menu_items,8,0);
            delete_menu(menu_items,9);
            if (selected_item<0)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You haven't selected any item.");
            else if(selected_item==0){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SHAILENDRA SINGH.",1);
write_data0();
if(fork())
wait(0);
else
execlp("clear","clear",(char *)NULL);
execlp("ls","ls",(char *)NULL);
execlp("konsole","konsole",(char *)NULL);
ESCAPE;
refresh();
delwin(menubar);
delwin(messagebar);

endwin();
}
            else if(selected_item==1){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu THINVENT TECH.",2);
write_data1();
}
            else if(selected_item==2){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu THINCLIENT.",3);
write_data2();
}
            else if(selected_item==3){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SOLAR COMPUTING",4);
write_data3();
}
            else if(selected_item==4){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu TECHNOCRATS.",5);
write_data4();
}
            else if(selected_item==5){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SENSORS.",6);
write_data5();
}
            else if(selected_item==6){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu NCURSESLIB.",7);
write_data6();
}
            else if(selected_item==7){
                wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu GCCCOMPILER.",8);
write_data7();
}          

            touchwin(stdscr);
            refresh();
        }
else if (key==KEY_F(2)) {
            menu_items=draw_menu1(20);
            selected_item=scroll_menu(menu_items,8,20);
            delete_menu(menu_items,9);
            if (selected_item<0)
                wprintw(messagebar,"You haven't selected any item.");
            else
                wprintw(messagebar,
                  "You have selected menu item %d.",selected_item+1);
            touchwin(stdscr);
            refresh();
        }}
    while (key!=ESCAPE);
    delwin(menubar);
    delwin(messagebar);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should pass arguments separately, and the first argument is the name of the file to be executed:

```
execlp("/usr/bin/telnet", "telnet", "0", "5000", (char *)NULL);
```

man [execlp(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp)

> int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
>
> The initial argument for these functions **is the name of a file that is
> to be executed**. The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the
> execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions **can be thought of as arg0,
> arg1, ..., argn**.