# The usage of execlp() in a c-program

Tags: c, execl

I have a question regarding execlp() in c.

I have the following programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>

void INThandler(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  struct passwd *pwd;
  char *lgn;
  char *cwd;
  char buff[PATH_MAX + 1];
  char  s1[10], s2[10];

  /*Um den Namen zu bekommen*/
  lgn = getlogin();
  pwd = getpwnam(lgn);

  /*Um den Hostnamen zu bekommen*/
  char hostname[128];
  gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname);

  /*Um das Arbeitsverzeichnis zu bekommen*/
  cwd = getcwd(buff, PATH_MAX + 1);
  if((cwd!=NULL)&& hostname!=NULL  && ((lgn=getlogin())!=NULL ||
(pwd!=NULL)))
    {
      signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
      while(1)
        {
          printf("%s@%s %s$", pwd->pw_name, hostname, cwd);
          if(scanf("%s %s",s1, s2)<1)
            return 1;
          printf("Befehl: %s\nArgument: %s\n",s1,s2);
          execlp(s1, s1, NULL);
          printf("Zhopa");
          return 1;
        }

    }
  return 0;
}

void INThandler(int sig) {
  char c;

  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  printf("Wollen Sie Program Verlassen? [y/n]");

  c = getchar();
  if(c == 'y' || c=='Y')
    exit(0);
  else
    signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
  getchar();
}
```

it should print the users name@hostname folder$ and take a linux command as an argument "ls -al"
after that it should start it with execlp(), but it doesn't work as I think t should.

I read all the articles here regarding this command, but I guess, I still don't understand, how to use it.

I would appreciate someone's help.

Comment: *" it doesn't work as I think it should"* means what exactly? – Note that execlp *replaces* the process image. It never returns to your program. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206961/c-program-exits-on-executing-execlp-function

Comment: as far as I understand, if I give that execlp() those strings s1, s2 (that would be execlp(s1, s2, NULL), s1 = "ls", s2 = "-al"), then it should run ls -al

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: The first argument is the program name, for example `execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL)`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/13264428/1187415.

Comment: if it try to run it like this: `execlp(s1,s1,s2, NULL)` - it doesn't run the program anyway

Comment: Does this execlp have to run the s1 program then at all???

Comment: Your current code shown has `execlp(s1, s1, NULL);` so it will ignore the argument. But if you replace it with `execlp(s1, s1, s2, NULL);` it works fine. I made this change in your code, compiled and ran it, entered `ls -l` at the prompt and it ran `ls -l` properly., So I'm not sure what you mean when you say, *It doesn't run the program anyway*.

Comment: By any means it should be .`execlp(..., (char*) NULL);`! (from `man execlp`: "*The list of arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, **this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.***") Best followed by `perror("execlp() failed");` as `exec*()` calls ***only** return on error*.

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a new process with a `fork()` and then in the new process (child) use the `execlp`. Here is the sample code. It doesn't handle any error and it works just with a command with exactly 1 parameter because that's what I've understood(e.g. `ls -all`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> /*Lib for waitpid*/
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>

void INThandler(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int pid = 0; /*PROCESS ID*/
  struct passwd *pwd;
  char *lgn;
  char *cwd;
  char buff[PATH_MAX + 1];
  char  s1[10], s2[10];

  /*Um den Namen zu bekommen*/
  lgn = getlogin();
  pwd = getpwnam(lgn);

  /*Um den Hostnamen zu bekommen*/
  char hostname[128];
  gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname);

  /*Um das Arbeitsverzeichnis zu bekommen*/
  cwd = getcwd(buff, PATH_MAX + 1);
  if((cwd!=NULL)&& hostname!=NULL  && ((lgn=getlogin())!=NULL ||
(pwd!=NULL)))
    {
      signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
      while(1)
        {
          printf("%s@%s %s$", pwd->pw_name, hostname, cwd);
          if(scanf("%s %s",s1, s2)<1)
            return 1;
          printf("Befehl: %s\nArgument: %s\n",s1,s2);
          pid = fork();
          if(pid == 0){ /*Child*/
            execlp(s1, s1, s2,(char*) NULL);
          }else if(pid > 0){ /*Father*/
            /*father waiting for the child*/
            waitpid(pid,NULL,0); 
          }
          printf("Zhopa");
        }

    }
  return 0;
}

void INThandler(int sig) {
  char c;

  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  printf("Wollen Sie Program Verlassen? [y/n]");

  c = getchar();
  if(c == 'y' || c=='Y')
    exit(0);
  else
    signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your signal handler invokes undefined behavior.

You can only call async-signal safe functions from within a signal handler.  [Per the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03):

> ... **the behavior is undefined** ... if the signal handler calls any
> function defined in this standard other than one of the functions
> listed in the following table.
>
> The following table defines a set of functions that shall be
> async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without
> restriction, from signal-catching functions. ...
>
> [table of async-signal-safe functions]
>
> Any function not in the above table may be unsafe with respect to signals. ...

This signal handler

```
void INThandler(int sig) {
  char c;

  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  printf("Wollen Sie Program Verlassen? [y/n]");

  c = getchar();
  if(c == 'y' || c=='Y')
    exit(0);
  else
    signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
  getchar();
}
```

has multiple non-async-signal-safe functions in it:

- `printf()`
- `getchar()`
- `exit()`

Those functions can not be safely called from within a signal handler.

Given your code, a likely place for this signal handler to be called would be when the process is blocked in `scanf()` - trying to read from `stdin`.  That likely involves a lock or mutex of some kind.  Yet your signal handler calls `getchar()` which also tries to read from `stdin`, which may be locked or in some indeterminate state.  If the main thread is blocked in `scanf()`, the asynchronous call to `getchar()` in the signal handler may deadlock or corrupt the internal structures used for `stdin`.